# How to change values of independently deployable classes while using the abstract factory pattern?

Tags: java, abstract-factory

I'm trying to learn some design patterns currently and made an example for the factory pattern that is independently deployable.

My problem now is that if I want to change any values of a Rectangle I would create a dependency on the Rectangle class. I could put those methods into the Shape interface but that wouldn't make much sense if the next shape I added was a circle.

How can I change the values without creating a dependency on the Rectangle class?

**Shape.java**

```
public interface Shape {}
```

**ShapeFactory.java**

```
public interface ShapeFactory {
    Shape create(String shape);
}
```

**Rectangle.java**

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private int top, left, bottom, right;

    public Rectangle(int top, int left, int bottom, int right) {
        setTopLeft(top, left);
        setBottomRight(bottom, right);
    }

    public void setTopLeft(int top, int left) {
        this.top = top;
        this.left = left;
    }

    public void setBottomRight(int bottom, int right) {
        this.bottom = bottom;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

**ShapeFactoryImpl.java**

```
public class ShapeFactoryImpl implements ShapeFactory {
    public Shape create(String shape) throws RuntimeException {
        if (shape.equals("rectangle")) 
            return new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    ShapeFactory shapeFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();

        app.setShapeFactory(new ShapeFactoryImpl());
        Shape rectangle = app.create("rectangle");

        // don't want this
        ((Rectangle) rectangle).setTopLeft(1,2);
        ((Rectangle) rectangle).setBottomRight(2,3);
    }

    private void setShapeFactory(ShapeFactoryImpl shapeFactory) {
        this.shapeFactory = shapeFactory;
    }

    private Shape create(String shape) {
        return shapeFactory.create(shape);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you probably have the wrong abstraction. Your `Shape` interface isn't really what your code is looking for. Its looking for a `setTopLeft()` and `setBottomRight()` methods. So maybe an interface `SettableCorners` that your _cornery_ classes can implement. The factory class could then decide what implementation of `SettableCorners` interface to return, or if that happens to be a `Shape` or not. This is way too much opinion based way too little knowledge of your scenario.

Comment: I think they call this a simple factory, where different types of objects are created based on input strings. In an abstract factory, the factory method doesn't create object based on input strings, but creates the same type of object every time.

Comment: @Scratte I use the string to make sure that the App part is indepentent from the concrete shapes. I could also use an enum but that would introduce a dependence on both sides. Other than that the factory creates the same object every time making this an abstract factory.

Comment: Try looking at this: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory

Comment: @Scratte I do not understand what you're trying to tell me with that. Do you mean I should make a `makeRectangle()` and once necessary a `makeCircle()` in the factory? Because that would make it not independent.